# Binomial probabilty invocation with R

Tags: r, probability

At a car hire service 50% of cars are returned on time. A sample of 20 car hires is studied. Is this the correct R invocation of `dbinom` in order to calculate all 20 cars are returned on time ? :

```
dbinom(x=20, size=20, prob=0.5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

We can check against what we know the answer to be (0.5^20, since 20 choose 20 is 1 and (0.5^20)*(0.5^(20-20)) = 0.5^20):

```
dbinom(x=20, size=20, prob=0.5)
# [1] 9.536743e-07

0.5^20
# [1] 9.536743e-07
```

From `help("dbinom")`:

> x, q   vector of quantiles.
>   ...
>   size   number of trials (zero or more).
>   prob   probability of success on each trial.

So here, `x` is our quantile (what is the probability there were 20 successes?), `size` is our number of trials (a sample of 20), and `prob` is the probability of success in each one (there is a 1/2 chance each car is returned timely).